# Clicking on 'More' under 'People and groups' through Server Error

Tags: permissions, master-page, custom-masterpage, system-master-page

I have created a custom master page and set it as system master page.when clicking on 'More' under 'People and groups'.

[image]

[image]

I have referred [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spdsupport/2008/07/10/how-to-fix-error-in-sharepoint-when-custom-master-page-is-applied/). all the tags are included in the custom master page. But No luck

Please suggest some idea to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have access to ULS? Try to read them once. Most probably you'll resolve your query.

Comment: You need to look into details of the error message to solve this issue and for that as mentioned in the error screenshot, you need to either reproduce the error on the SharePoint Server by remote login to the Server (this will work only if CustomeError Mode is RemoteOnly) **OR** Ask SharePoint Admin to set the CustomError Mode to "Off" for that web application web.config so that detailed error message can be viewed even from client machine also.

Comment: I have checked in ULS .i did't get any idea from the log file. @ThinkB4Code

Comment: Once try to change master page to default i.e. settle or oslo and access the `more group`. If thats work fine, it means there is some problem with the custom master page only. And if that is the case, try to get the exact error by the methods suggested by @Yayati